# 2nd Reaction not being added to a cog command

Tags: python, discord.py, nextcord

I lately switched to cogs in nextcord.
I added a poll command, a simple one where you just have to react.

```
    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(moderate_members=True)
    async def poll(self, ctx, *, content:str=None):
        if content == None:
            content = "Lorem Ipsum"
        embed=nextcord.Embed(title=f"{content}", description="• ✅ for Yes\n• ❌ for No.",  color=discord.Colour.random())
        embed.set_author(name=ctx.author.display_name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar.url)
        embed.set_footer(text="Don't choose both man.")
        message = await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
        #adding the reactions the reactions
        await message.add_reaction("✅")
        await message.add_reaction("❌")

    @poll.error
    async def poll_error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
            embed = nextcord.Embed(
            title="<:mod:955112014408208455> Not Authorized",
            description=
            "Sorry but this command can only be used by members with `Moderate Members` permission.",
            colour=nextcord.Colour.random())
            await ctx.reply(content="ALERT!!", embed=embed)
```

The line `await message.add_reaction("❌")` isn't functioning. Can someone solve or either explain this to me.

Comment: You have an error handler for that command, so if it raises anything other than `MissingPermissions` then the error will get swallowed & you'll never know. Consider adding a print over there or re-raising it to catch it in another handler.

Comment: @stijndcl How do I do that, can you show just a line?

Comment: It's only one line, if I show it then I'll give you the solution. Just Google "python print exception" or "python raise exception". I've basically given it to you in this comment already...

Comment: @stijndcl It's not working... The reaction isn't being added and no error is showing.

Comment: You haven't showed what you tried so that's not very useful to me

Comment: @stijndcl I have the issue fixed. Seems like it was a error because forks got mixed.

Answer (score -1):

embed=discord.Embed uh???
yo gotta change that

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).